# Parse JSON to CSV Twitter Data KeyError: 'user'

Tags: python, json, csv, twitter

I am trying to parse some tweets data I collected in a JSON file right now. The problem is some of the tweets don't have 'user' or 'place' in them. As a result, I get messages like:

```
  File "<stdin>", line 18, in <module>
  KeyError: 'user'
```

So I tried to add an if-else statement, but it is still giving me the error message. What is the next step?

```
for line in lines:
    try:
            tweet = json.loads(line)

            # Ignore retweets!
            if tweet.has_key("retweeted_status") or not tweet.has_key("text"):
                    continue

            # Fetch text from tweet
            text = tweet["text"].lower()

            # Ignore 'manual' retweets, i.e. messages starting with RT             
            if text.find("rt ") > -1:
                    continue

            tweets_text.append( text )
            # I added an if-else statement, but it's still having be the error message
            if tweet['user']:
                    tweets_location.append( tweet['user']['location'] )
            else:
                    tweets_location.append("")

    except ValueError:
            pass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By doing `tweet['user']` in the if statement you are assuming the key `user` exist, which raises the `KeyError`. You can test if the key is in the dict by doing `if 'user' in tweet`. Alternatively, you can handle the `KeyError` similar to how to handle `ValueError`

```
try:
    ....
    try:
        tweets_location.append( tweet['user']['location'] )
    except KeyError:
        tweets_location.append("")
except ValueError:
        pass
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get).

```
        if tweet.get('user'):
                tweets_location.append(tweet['user'].get('location', ''))
        else:
                tweets_location.append("")
```

See [Why dict.get(key) instead of dict[key]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041405/why-dict-getkey-instead-of-dictkey)

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a KeyError. If you want to check whether the key is in the dictionary, do:

```
if 'user' in tweet:
    tweets_location.append( tweet['user']['location'] )
```

Or you could embed it in a try..except:

```
try:
    tweets_location.append( tweet['user']['location'] )
except KeyError:
    tweets_location.append('')
```

Alternatively, you may use the get method of dict, as suggested by XrXrXr. The get method gives you a convenient way of providing a default value, i.e., so you can do it all in one line:

```
tweets_location.append( tweet.get('user', '').get('location', '') )
```

This defaults to the empty string if 'user' is not a key in tweet, and also to the empty string if the 'location' is not a key of tweet['user']